# Tokenizing tweets as ngrams in R

Tags: r, twitter, tidytext

I am trying to tokenize a collection of tweets as bigrams. I am using `tidytext::unnest_tokens()` function in R to do this. The function takes either `token = "tweets"` or `token = "ngrams"` as one of the arguments. If I give `token = "ngrams"` as the argument, I cannot strip url and retain tagging features, which can be achieved by giving `token = "tweets"`.

I am currently working with `token = "ngrams"`. I would like to know if I can first tokenize the tweets using `token = "tweets"` and then re-tokenize them as bigrams. Or if there is any other elegant way to do this, I would be grateful to know.

Comment: You might want to check the quanteda package. Or first use the textclean package to clean the tweets before using tidytext.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful